# Which Programs Are Included In The LiveCD That Are Removed Upon Installation?

Tags: 13.10, apt, live-cd, preinstallation

I've noticed when booting up Ubuntu 13.10 – Desktop X86-64 disc in "Try Without Installing" mode that Gparted is pre-installed, however if you install Ubuntu to your hard drive the package is removed (or purged? not sure which) during the installation process.

I know for a fact that Gparted is pre-installed in the LiveCD rather than installed by script during LiveCD boot, because I've examined the `filesystem.squashfs` file. This makes me wonder what other programs are pre-installed but removed during installation. Is there a full listing available somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://askubuntu.com/a/436700/248158 is a great answer but if you no longer have the file `iso/casper/filesystem.manifest-remove` to look at the list or just want another way you may be able to get the information (in more ugly form) from `/var/log/apt`.

- Assuming you have the oldest compressed `history.log` file available (which you normally should have if you did a clean install of 13.10 (and don't use things like Bleachbit)), you should see something close to this:

  $ ls -l /var/log/apt
  total 120
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  5024 Mar 19 07:40 history.log
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1252 Feb 27 07:29 history.log.1.gz
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  2156 Jan 31 06:03 history.log.2.gz
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1288 Dec 31 11:14 history.log.3.gz
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  3232 Nov 27 07:22 history.log.4.gz
  -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18813 Oct 31 07:11 history.log.5.gz
  -rw-r----- 1 root adm  28064 Mar 19 07:40 term.log
  -rw-r----- 1 root adm   3331 Feb 27 07:29 term.log.1.gz
  -rw-r----- 1 root adm   4862 Jan 31 06:03 term.log.2.gz
  -rw-r----- 1 root adm   3685 Dec 31 11:14 term.log.3.gz
  -rw-r----- 1 root adm   9058 Nov 27 07:22 term.log.4.gz
  -rw-r----- 1 root adm  12452 Oct 31 07:11 term.log.5.gz
  $
- In here, `history.log.5.gz` is of interest. So, to get the uncompressed version, run:

  zcat /var/log/apt/history.log.5.gz > ~/Desktop/output.txt
- Look at that file with the text editor you like. Looking from the top, you'll see a lot of "installs" (very long lines) but if you go down carefully a few lines, you'll come to a line beginning with `Purge:`. That is also a very long line and will list the packages, including `gparted`, removed as part of the setting up of your OS.
- If you like the terminal, you can extract only that line with:

  grep -m 1 "Purge:" ~/Desktop/output.txt

Answer (score 2):

I think it has something to do with some voodoo with [ubuntu seeds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SeedManagement) (can some one who knows more elaborate please.. I'd like to know too ;) ) The installer seed defines what packages are needed for installation but removed later. However I don't know whether this has become obsolete as it seems to be last updated at the time of gutsy gibbon.

At the time of installation the the full list of packages to be removed is found in the file `iso/casper/filesystem.manifest-remove`

The data from the trusty iso:

`apt-clone
archdetect-deb
btrfs-tools
casper
cifs-utils
cryptsetup
cryptsetup-bin
dmraid
dpkg-repack
ecryptfs-utils
firefox-locale-en
firefox-locale-es
firefox-locale-zh-hans
gir1.2-json-1.0
gir1.2-timezonemap-1.0
gir1.2-xkl-1.0
gparted
jfsutils
keyutils
kpartx
kpartx-boot
language-pack-en
language-pack-en-base
language-pack-es
language-pack-es-base
language-pack-gnome-en
language-pack-gnome-en-base
language-pack-gnome-es
language-pack-gnome-es-base
language-pack-gnome-zh-hans
language-pack-gnome-zh-hans-base
language-pack-zh-hans
language-pack-zh-hans-base
libcryptsetup4
libdebian-installer4:amd64
libdevmapper-event1.02.1:amd64
libdmraid1.0.0.rc16
libecryptfs0
libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a:amd64
libnss3-1d:amd64
linux-signed-generic
linux-signed-image-3.13.0-14-generic
linux-signed-image-generic
localechooser-data
lupin-casper
lvm2
metacity
python3-icu
python3-pam
rdate
reiserfsprogs
sbsigntool
ubiquity
ubiquity-casper
ubiquity-frontend-gtk
ubiquity-plugin-ubuntuone
ubiquity-slideshow-ubuntu
ubiquity-ubuntu-artwork
user-setup
watershed
xfsprogs`